# PHP Tag Removes Last Newline in Document

Tags: php, html, formatting, newline

This issue is purely in the interest of having tidy HTML code output.

In a simple PHP file, you can choose when to have PHP embedded in the document by using the  tags. However, it appears that when this tag is used directly above a regular HTML element, the newline separating the two is apparently removed or ignored.

Observe the following code in PHP

```
<div>
<?php echo "This is some extra text." ?>
</div>
```

The output is as follows

```
<div>
This is some extra text.</div>
```

However, if I add something directly after the tag,

```
<div>
<?php echo "This is some extra text." ?> Now the newline is honored.
</div>
```

it appears the newline is honored:

```
<div>
This is some extra text. Now the newline is honored.
</div>
```

Again, this is purely a cosmetic issue and has nothing to do with incorrectly rendering a page. I want the source code to be nice and readable, and certain I could add in the first echo the "\n" character at the end, but this does not feel satisfying and would also be rather annoying. Is there any remedy to this problem, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Using a template engine such as **Twig** should prevent that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a long standing issue with PHP. Basically, if your close tag has a newline directly after it, PHP eats it. But if there's some other character immediately after the close tag (even a whitespace), then any linebreaks after it are respected.

E.g.

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>\nWorld
```

produces:

```
HelloWorld
```

And

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>\n\nWorld
```

produces:

```
Hello⏎
World
```

However,

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?> \nWorld
```

produces

```
Hello ⏎
World
```

So the workaround is to either remember to add a newline at the end of the output of each block, or to insert a space between the close tag and the newline after it.

Comment: If you ever wonder [why](https://brian.moonspot.net/php-history-newline-closing-tag).

Answer (score 0):

Try having it like to force the line break:

```
<div>
<?php echo "This is some extra text." ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` character is invisible to you, but when you add the extra text after, you are hitting return/enter.

If you want the added text to have the newline character, just do the following:

```
<?php echo "This is some extra text.\n" ?>
```