# PHP tags deleting trailing newline

Tags: php, newline, whitespace

When I run the following PHP code from the command line:

```
$ php test.php
```

where the contents of test.php are as follows

```
Foo
<? echo "Hello World" ?>
Bar
```

I am getting as output:

```
Foo
Hello WorldBar
```

instead of:

```
Foo
Hello World
Bar
```

which is what I could swear previous versions of PHP would output.
It is though the closing php tag now consumes the following newline
character which wasn't happening in earlier versions of PHP as far
as I can remember. Is there a setting somewhere in some php.ini or other configuration
file which toggles this or similar whitespace munching behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Which PHP version have are you now using, and which one(s) previously?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Tag Removes Last Newline in Document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723835/php-tag-removes-last-newline-in-document)

Comment: For Reference: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=21891

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Foo
<? echo "Hello World" ?> 
Bar
```

(there is 1 space after the `?>`, e.g. as a string it is "?> ") will output:

```
Foo
Hello World
Bar
```

This behavior is specified in the PHP manual (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) as:

> when the PHP interpreter hits the ?> closing tags, it simply starts outputting
>   whatever it finds (except for an immediately following newline [...])

Now, to answer your question "Is there a setting somewhere in some php.ini or other configuration file which toggles this or similar whitespace munching behavior?"

No there isn't, according to the link/bug report provided by Orangepill (bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=21891). In the bug report, it is stated that there will never be an option to control this behavior because it makes writing portable scripts harder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `\n` in the end of your string in echo

try this

```
Foo
<? echo "Hello World\n" ?>
Bar
```